# In python, how do I call the correct constructor from the method of a mixin class?

Tags: python, python-2.7, oop, inheritance, multiple-inheritance

Say I have two container classes that behave slightly differently, but have a lot of common methods.  I use a mixin class to add these methods to both containers.

For example:

```
class SpamContainer(Mixin, BaseClass):
    def __init__(self, spam):
        super(SpamContainer, self).__init__(spam)

class DifferentSpamContainer(Mixin, DifferentBaseClass):
    def __init__(self, spam):
        super(DifferentSpamContainer, self).__init__(spam)

class Mixin(object):
    # has no __init__()

    def useful_method(self):
        for s in self.spam:
            # do something
```

Now I want to add a new method to `Mixin` that creates and returns a new container object - if `self` is a `SpamContainer`, I want to create one of those, whereas if it's a `DifferentSpamContainer`, I want to create one of those.  How can I call the correct constructor from within a method of `Mixin`?

I thought maybe I could use something like this:

```
class Mixin(object):
    def method(self, spam):
        return self.__init__(spam)
```

or

```
class Mixin(object):
    def another_method(self, spam):
        return self.__class__(spam)
```

but I can't get it to work.

I'm using python 2.7.

Comment: Be very careful using Mixins to anything non-trivial, they can very quickly get out of hand. Why do you want to put construction functionality into the instance-level of a mixin (e.g. as opposed to just calling the init method (or a class level constructor) on the base class?

Comment: I don't think I understood why can't You just use the constructors of the subclasses.?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You use a [`classmethod`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#classmethod):

```
class Mixin(object):
    @classmethod
    def alternate_constructor(cls, spam):
        return cls(spam)
```

---

Note that your use of mixins here seems to be a little off.  Frequently, when using inheritance (single or multiple), you'll want to call up to the method on the base-class.  e.g. in your case, `Mixin` and the various classes that it is being mixed with can't both have their constructors called.  In fact, you aren't even calling `__init__` in `BaseClass` for `SpamContainer` for example.  This is a bit strange.  If you're going to be doing any work with multiple inheritance, I strongly suggest you read [Super Considered Super!](https://rhettinger.wordpress.com/2011/05/26/super-considered-super/) and companion article [Super considered harmful](https://fuhm.net/super-harmful/).  This will help you to know the pitfalls of multiple inheritance (and how to avoid them).

Comment: You forgot to declare the `cls` argument.

Comment: @jwodder -- Thanks.  I was already moving on to "You should be careful if you are going to work with Mixins".

Comment: Thanks, I've edited my question to include ``super()`` calls to the base classes.  I'll read a bit about ``@classmethod`` and your other links before excepting your answer.